# Who has added me to their circles in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

How can I view the list of people who have me in their circles on Google+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to your Google+ page
2. Bring up the left-hand sidebar and click on **People** (formerly Circles)
   [image: Google+ People]
3. Once in your **People** section you can select **Have you in circles** from the top, middle, grey bar
   [image: Have you in circles]

Another way to see at least *some* of the Google+ circles you are in (larger, public circles) is using the [Public Circles Database](http://publiccircles.appspot.com/)- though this *definitely* doesn't cover the more quotidien circles (e.g. your best friend's friend list probably won't be in here).

You'll need your 21-digit Google ID number:

> You can find it in your browser's address bar on your profile page. Or
>   use this link: http://plus.google.com/me
>
> For example: My profile page
>   is: `https://plus.google.com/102235836543922327908/posts` and my Google+
>   ID is `102235836543922327908`

From there you can search using your Google ID
[image: Search Public Circles]